# How to insert multiple values with popup LOV in Oracle APEX?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

I want to find a way to insert multiple values in a link table, for that I use popup LOV item, using this item users can choose multiple values. And I want to insert that values to link table.

I tried with

```
INSERT INTO LINK_TABLE (FK_1, FK_2)
VALUES (:P2_POPUP, :P2_RECORD2);
```

When I try to insert more than one value, I got `ORA-01722: invalid number`

Comment: I'd say that you have to explain it a lot better. What "multiple values"? What does LoV do? Do you allow users to select more than a single value? What data are you actually trying to insert?

Comment: Sorry for bad explanation, users can select more than one value in POPUP LoV.

Comment: I have table which need tags, every record in that table can have more than one tag. For that I need to use link table and POP LoV which can select more than one value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I presume that

- `P2_POPUP` contains a single value, while
- `P2_RECORD2` contains one or more values selected by user

  - it means that Apex stores them as colon-separated values, which - furthermore ...
  - ... means that you have to split it into rows

For example: `TEMP` CTE "simulates" values that `P2_POPUP` (`1`) and `P2_RECORD2` (`10:30:40`) contain. Query from line #3 to line #6 creates several rows out of it:

```
SQL> with temp (p2_popup, p2_record2) as
  2    (select 1, '10:30:40' from dual)
  3  select p2_popup,
  4    regexp_substr(p2_record2, '[^:]+', 1, level) p2_rec
  5  from temp
  6  connect by level <= regexp_count(p2_record2, ':') + 1;

  P2_POPUP P2_REC
---------- --------------------------------
         1 10
         1 30
         1 40

SQL>
```

It means that your code would look like this:

```
insert into link_table (fk_1, fk_2)
select :P2_POPUP,
       regexp_substr(:P2_RECORD2, '[^:]+', 1, level) p2_rec
from dual
connect by level <= regexp_count(:P2_RECORD2, ':') + 1;
```

Comment: You can simplify this code with apex_string.split http://www.grassroots-oracle.com/2019/02/function-based-tables.html